# Are there some ways to install a smaller new linux on a older one?

Tags: linux, rhel

The company's redhat linux is too old to install something, but it cannot be replaced with new one. I want to install some software but there are a lot of dependencies that version is too low. I want to know whether there are some ways to install some "small system" on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are, but you might want to hear about other solutions first:

1. Try to find **backports** for the software you need. You're saying that you can't install the package you want because of dependencies, but there's a chance you just needed this term to find it.
2. If you have access to the source code of the desired program, you might try to compile it on your own. There's a chance, probably a good one, that it will work with what you have (or otherwise, complain during compilation).
3. Maybe the package you need could be obtained with statically linked libraries? Always worth a shot.

This list is not exhaustive, but I think that it should be tried first. If all of this fails, or you are just curious about the thing you're asking, these are some of your options:

1. Containers - you could use Docker to quickly obtain filesystem image. That way should be easy and work well enough.
2. Virtualization of some other kind. Install another system within virtual machine - easy enough.
3. Use some equivalent of `debootstrap` and `chroot` in; don't count too much on it, though - it often happens that there are assumptions about the 'host', like depending on some kernel version.

This is probably not the definite end of trickeries that might be put to use. You could, for example, run some piece of software remotely and just make it look like it was running on your original machine, using NFS.

And last but not least: if your machine can't be upgraded because of it's responsibilities, probably running new software isn't it's another responsibility. Separation would probably do some good, but that's all subject of your company policy.